# C# constant string calling

Tags: c#

I have made some constant string:

```
public const string a_sub  = "S";
public const string b_sub  = "Y"; 
public const string c_sub  = "X"; 
public const string d_sub  = "W"; 
// ...
```

And i have a text:

```
string str = "This is a test";
```

I want to do something like:

```
foreach(char c in str)
{
    str.Replace(c,c_sub);
```

let's pretend c is a, then  it would be:

```
str.Replace(c, a_sub);
```

if c would be d, then it would be:

```
str.Replace(c, d_sub);
```

and so on

```
}
```

But i can not figure out a way to do it, some help..please?

Comment: You wanna replace every character with `S` in your string? Can you please be more specific? Show short but complete program demonstrating your problem.

Comment: Your code currently isn't making too much sense. Perhaps try expressing in words what you're trying to do.

Comment: what do you need to archive? what is c_sub?

Comment: so it would replace the text with the constant

Comment: Do you need something like "This is a test" -> "ThiS iS a teSt"? Could you please give us expected result?

Comment: Are you trying to convert all letters to uppercase?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Write an input string and what the output should be. "I have string 'jfhweh' and I want it to become 'fhjkwe'"

Comment: so you would like to replace chars in your text with these const?

Comment: yeah, this is what i want to do

Comment: can you do a dictionary? var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); dict.Add("a", "S"); dict.Add("b", "Y");, etc. and then iterate and replace chars

Comment: i wanna do something like
[code]
foreach(char c in str)
{
    str.Replace(c,c_sub);
    // if  c is a, then replace the str with a_sub 
   // else if c is b then replace with b_sub
}

Comment: defining string constants like this will make your code much longer and it's not recommended, using some Dictionary is better.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Dictionary and a Stringbuilder:

```
Dictionary<char, char> mapper = new Dictionary<char, char>
{
   {'a','S'},
   {'b','D'},
   .......
};

var str = "aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb";
var sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
{
    sb[i] = mapper[sb[i]];
}
var newStr = sb.ToString(); // SSSSSSSSDDDDDDDD
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what i was searching for!

Answer (score 2):

Define your const in the dictionary

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"a", "S"},
    {"b", "Y"},
    {"c", "X"},
    ...
};
```

And then iterate via this dictionary

```
var str = "This is a test";
foreach (var c in dict)
{
    str = str.Replace(c.Key, c.Value);
}
```

Comment: @QwzzJean note that the code here may replace your string in sequential effect, meaning every replacement before may be next replaced by some other value found via the next entry in the `dict`. Such as if all `a` was replaced by `f`, then if your `dict` has `f` mapped to `z`, it then will be replaced with `z`, so finally `a` will be replaced with `z` not `f` as you may want initially.

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach.

By using reflection and the StringBuilder for a temp result(it will help to avoid wrong/repeated replacements)

```
string str = "This is a test";
StringBuilder  result = new StringBuilder();
for(int idx = 0; idx < str.Length; idx++)
{
    char newChar = str[idx];
    if (newChar != ' ')
    {
        string propName = string.Format("{0}_sub", newChar.ToString().ToLowerInvariant());
        // program is the name of your class...
        var field = typeof(Program).GetField(propName);
        if(field != null)
        {
            // where null in case of static class
            //replace with the name of the class where the consts are
            newChar = field.GetValue(null).ToString().ToCharArray()[0];
        }
    }

    result.Append(newChar);
}
str = result.ToString();
```

I find this solution a little bit more complex for beginners, but easier to maintain the changes in the constants.
A weak point...it will not cover all possible characters because of variable naming conventions.

**Edit**

Thanks to @Hopeless, for the comments to improve the answer avoiding unnecessary dummy classes

Comment: You don't need a dummy class. Just define the constants in the same class and use Reflection normally, such as like this `field = this.GetType().GetField(prefix + "_sub", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)`.

Comment: As I said, in case you use a static class, you need to use a dummy class. I might be wrong, but I think you cannot use `this` for static classes to `GetType` and later `GetValue`. If I am wrong, let me know :)

Comment: in that case you should know the type name beforehand and use `typeof(YourStaticType)` instead.

Comment: But can you later use `GetValue` of `this` ?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, strings are immutable. To alter a string's contents, you need to create a new string.

In your case, you seem to be replacing all the string's characters by `a_sub`, so you can simply repeat your `a_sub` character for *n* times, with *n* being the length of the original string:

```
string str = "This is a test";
const char a_sub = 'S';
str = new string(a_sub, str.Length);
```

**Edit**: If `a_sub` needs to be a string (not a character), you can use:

```
string str = "This is a test";
const string a_sub = "S";
str = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(a_sub, str.Length));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Dictionary<char, char> GetChar = new Dictionary<char, char>()
        {
            {'a','S'},
            {'b','Y'}

        };

        string str = "This is a test";

        string newStr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            newStr = newStr + GetChar[str[i]];
        }
```

I guess this is what you want. Using dictionary is better idea and newStr will return what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to perfom a sort of chiffre like ROT13, but with a non-ordered dictionary (as I would call it, since your translation is not in an alphabetical order).

Since C# seems to lack a handy function like Python's translate:

```
# ... Map a to d, b to e, and c to f.
dict = str.maketrans("abc", "def")
print(dict)

# Translate this value.
value = "aabbcc"
result = value.translate(dict)
print(result)

#Output: ddeeff
```

You'll have to implement the map manually, by using a dictionary instead of constants.

**Be careful to write the translation to a new variable instead of replacing the old one**, since you work with an unordered set of keys and thus could later replace characters, that you just translated already (in your example would first substitute "a" with "s" and later "s" with "h").

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Test
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var d = new Dictionary<char, char> 
        {
            {'a', 'S'},
            {'b', 'Y'}, 
            {'c', 'X'}, 
            {'d', 'W'}, 
            {'e', 'V'},
            {'f', 'U'},
            {'g', 'T'},
            {'h', 'S'},
            {'i', 'R'},
            {'j', 'Q'},
            {'k', 'P'},
            {'l', 'O'},
            {'m', 'n'},
            {'n', 'M'},
            {'o', 'L'},
            {'p', 'K'},
            {'q', 'J'},
            {'r', 'I'},
            {'s', 'H'},
            {'t', 'G'},
            {'u', 'F'},
            {'v', 'E'},
            {'w', 'D'},
            {'x', 'C'},
            {'Y', 'B'},
            {'z', 'A'}
        };

        var input = "This is a test";

        var result = new StringBuilder("");
        foreach (var c in input.ToLower())
        {
            if (d.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                result.Append(d[c]);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append(c);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
    }
}
```